# Handling multiple touch in android such as Pinch In and Pinch Out

Tags: android, multi-touch, touch-event

I am trying to achieve multi touch in such as way that when user pinch out with two finger outside I need to handle one event and on pinching In other event. No ZOOMING IN or ZOOMING OUT NEEDED.

So I am handling onTouchEvent on layout, but could not get conditions true for pinching in and pinching out.

Here is code,

```
 layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int mActivePointerId;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            mActivePointerId = motionEvent.getPointerId(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "COUNT"+motionEvent.getPointerCount());
            if(motionEvent.getPointerCount() > 1){
                if((motionEvent.getAction() == motionEvent.ACTION_UP) && (motionEvent.getAction() == motionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN))
                Log.d(TAG, "Multi Touch Upwards ");
                return true;
            } else if((motionEvent.getAction() == motionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (motionEvent.getAction() == motionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)){
                Log.d(TAG, "Multi Touch DownWard ");
                return true;
            }
             else{
                Log.d(TAG, "It is signal Touch");

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I referred this link but not very clear [example](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-3-understanding-touch-events/1775)
Any suggestion to make it work...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it work with the help of `ScaleGestureDector`. Just need to check the scalefactor if the scale factor would be more then 1 then it would be Pinch Out otherwise Pinch In.

Here is good example, it is very easy and fits your need well, 
Just follow the instruction from this link [ScaleGestureDector](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Pinch_Gesture_Detection_Tutorial_using_Android_Studio)

Comment: the value is always above 1 , is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

So , you need to use a GestureDetector.

Whatsoever you need to do with that pinching out and in, you can most likely do with a gesture listener.

Check out this link and take 5 minutes to read, your answer is there for sure: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Just for the record:I have been using GestureListener recently ,so it's a "sure thing".

Comment: Nope, it has a few methods -about 7-8 ,for gestures.

Anyways, I will try to find you exactly what you need later a bit.